# Master View doesn't appear as specified in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, viewcontroller

I'm having an issue with my `Master View controller` not appearing as specified by my storyboard.

By searching on this (awesome) site, I learned to check into my `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods. I believe my issue is that `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning `'int 0'`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

My MasterViewController.m:

```
#import "ParentMasterViewController.h"
#import "ParentDetailViewController.h"
#import "NewEventDataController.h"
#import "NewEvent.h"

@interface ParentMasterViewController ()
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end

@implementation ParentMasterViewController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.dataController = [[NewEventDataController alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{   
    return [self.dataController countOfList];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

    if (formatter == nil)
    {
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; // forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // note: Add some code like this to create a new cell if there are none to reuse
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NewEvent *eventAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [[cell textLabel] setText:eventAtIndex.event];

    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)eventAtIndex.date]];

    return cell;
}
```

In addition, my NewEventDataController.m:

```
#import "NewEventDataController.h"
#import "NewEvent.h"

@interface NewEventDataController ()

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList;

@end

@implementation NewEventDataController

- (void)initializeDefaultDataList
{
    NSMutableArray *eventList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    self.masterNewEventList = eventList;

    NewEvent *event;

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    event = [[NewEvent alloc] initWithName:@"Event" date:today];

    [self addNewEventWithEvent:event];
}

- (void)setMasterNewEventList:(NSMutableArray *)newList
{
    if (_masterNewEventList != newList)
        _masterNewEventList = [newList mutableCopy];
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        [self initializeDefaultDataList];

        return self;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSUInteger)countOfList
{
    return [self.masterNewEventList count];
}

- (NewEvent *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex
{
    return [self.masterNewEventList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
}

- (void)addNewEventWithEvent:(NewEvent *)event
{
    [self.masterNewEventList addObject:event];
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance for taking a look.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint on self.dataController = [[NewEventDataController alloc] init]; and see if it gets called.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does. Immediately after response, the debug shows `_dataController = NewEventDataController (NewEventDataController*) 0x07470a00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

If I am not interpreting wrong than you have copied this code from somewhere and forgot to change implementation of this method. Change it to have one section for every row or comment out the whole method:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm really green with Objective-C and XCode in general. So I'm trying to modify Apple's 'BirdSighting' app from 'Your Second iOS App' to try to see how all this works. Thanks for the help, I'll take a look there.

Comment: Pleasure. I suggest you start by reading Apple Guides and documentation.

Comment: They suggest I bounce back and forth, but I will. I commented out the line I added `return [self.dataController countOfList];`, added the line `return 1;` and it does the same. I changed it to `return 2;` which just added another of the non-storyboard specified cells. Which was good in a way, at least I know for sure what that is doing.